# Android Spinner is working -- but can't parse and pass the selected value

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to pass a value from an android spinner selection into a url. All of my other vars are passing and the toast on the spinner in displaying the correct spinner choice when selected. (for purposes here, the code doesn't show all vars.)

My log shows the country VAR  as NULL. Need to get the "country0" value to pass like the others.  How can I make this happen?

thanks

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onCreate");
    mContext = this; //TODO legacy may not be needed
    SERVER = this.getString(R.string.mygallerist_server_base);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        uid = settings.getString("uid", NOT_SET); 

        //SPINNER
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.countries_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        mOver35CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Over35);
        class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

                 //SPINNER PARSING     
            @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> country0,
              View view, int pos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(country0.getContext(), "The country is " +
            country0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView country0 ) {
        // Do nothing.

            }

        }

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
            final String country = country0;///MAYBE THIS IS WHAT IS WRONG

        setPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // If all fields filled in then go to server
                String country1 = country; /// OR MAYBE THIS IS WHAT IS WRONG

            String userName = mUserNameEditText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something in your question, but when you select the value for the Toast, you could just set the value of a private member, then read this value in your onClick, (being as you know you're getting the correct value in the onItemSelected)

```
 private String countrySelection;
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> country0, View view, int pos, long id) {
      countrySelection = country0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
      Toast.makeText(country0.getContext(), "The country is " + countrySelection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 ...
 final String country = countrySelection;
 setPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {
           sendDataToServer(country, ...);
```

Does this solve your issue?

Edit...

What type is country0 in this context? (I don't have comment privileges yet)

```
 final String country = country0;///MAYBE THIS IS WHAT IS WRONG
```

Comment: I was just about to write up pretty much the same suggestion. This is pretty much how I handle the Spinner in my application and it works flawlessly.

Comment: country value still the only one coming up NULL. Tried a few diff ways.This is what it is now:       final String country1 = countrySelection;
        setPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v) {
          String userName = mUserNameEditText.getText().toString();
          String userId = uid;
          String over_35 = "";
      more code............
           
          }
          else
     acctinfo(country1, userName, email0, strPassword1, userType, over_35, userId);